# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception'

Tags: gmail-api

I have created my a function to retrieve message from my Own Gamil Account by using CodeIgniter(PHP Framework). I have tried to follow some recommendation from stackOverlow but there was still not complete. so the code has asked me to login and show the Fatal error: Uncaught exception `Google_Service_Exception`.

Could you tell me what is the real problem ? could you direct me to right code?

```
        $this->load->library('google');
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setClientId('000000-00000000000.apps.googleusercontent.com');
        $client->setClientSecret('0000-0000000@developer.gserviceaccount.com');
        $client->setRedirectUri(base_url('manage-reservation/get_mess'));
        $client->addScope('email');
        $client->addScope('profile');     
        $client->addScope('https://mail.google.com');           
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        //$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);

        //$client->setDeveloperKey('1052192456244-qjjb1unv7rolpg0gmm0p98osv7lpsqo9@developer.gserviceaccount.com');
        //$client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');

        $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

       $optParams = [];
        $optParams['maxResults'] = 5; // Return Only 5 Messages
        $optParams['labelIds'] = 'INBOX'; // Only show messages in Inbox
        $messages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',$optParams);
        $list = $messages->getMessages();
        $messageId = $list[0]->getId(); // Grab first Message


        $optParamsGet = [];
        $optParamsGet['format'] = 'full'; // Display message in payload
        $message = $service->users_messages->get('me',$messageId,$optParamsGet);
        $messagePayload = $message->getPayload();
        $headers = $message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
        $parts = $message->getPayload()->getParts();

        $body = $parts[0]['body'];
        $rawData = $body->data;
        $sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
        $decodedMessage = base64_decode($sanitizedData);

        var_dump($decodedMessage);
```

Error Appeared :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message 'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?maxResults=5&labelIds=INBOX:
>   (401) Login Required' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\host\airbnb-mail-manage\code-application\third_party\Google\Http\REST.php:110
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\host\airbnb-mail-manage\code-application\third_party\Google\Http\REST.php(62):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request),
>   Object(Google_Client)) #1 [internal function]:
>   Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client),
>   Object(Google_Http_Request)) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\host\airbnb-mail-manage\code-application\third_party\Google\Task\Runner.php(174): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\host\airbnb-mail-manage\code-application\third_party\Google\Http\REST.php(46):
>   Google_Task_Runner->run() #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\host\airbnb-mail-manage\code-application\third_party\Google\Client.php(593):
>   Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client),
>   Object(Google_Http_Request)) #5 C:\ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\host\airbnb-mail-manage\code-application\third_party\Google\Http\REST.php
>   on line 110

Comment: Are you using client_secret in the line $client->setClientSecret('0000-0000000@developer.gserviceaccount.com'); This looks like you are giving service account email. When you register your application in developers console, what ever client_secret you got, that should be given here.

Comment: I tried to hide it becuase of some security, but if you want I can give you below: 1052192456244-qjjb1unv7rolpg0gmm0p98osv7lpsqo9@developer.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: @samphors: Please share the code for your redirect Uri where you perhaps are saving OAUTH Token (base_url('manage-reservation/get_mess'))
It seems that you are not completing the OAuth cycle hence giving 401 exception